# QSS for ComboBox popup does not work on MacOS

Tags: qtstylesheets, pyqt6

I would like change styles for popup of QComboBox but it works just on Windows and does not work on MacOS.

Here is my QSS:

```
#bit_combo QAbstractItemView {
    font-size: 12px;
    border: none;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    outline: 0px;
}

#bit_combo QAbstractItemView::item {
    padding: 15px;
}

#bit_combo QAbstractItemView::item:hover {  
    background-color: rgb(214, 214, 214);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

#bit_combo QAbstractItemView::item:selected {   
    background-color: rgb(214, 214, 214);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Add `combobox-popup: 0;` to the main combo selector QSS, or use fusion/windows style on the combo, or set a new QStyledItemDelegate.